# How to edit record value in Clearquest

Tags: clearquest

Mistakenly, I have put the wrong value in one the record in ClearQuest, now I want to edit the value but unable to do it. I have put the value in following steps:

- login to ClearQuest for Windows Client
- **Action** > **New**

[image]

As per Screenshot, I take this way to update the record value.

Here I updated one of the record value and further I found value is wrong, now please help me to edit the record as the same value is reflecting when I try to create new CQ/Incident.

This is the record and in this named *Build Name* text box I have put wrong value mistakenly and need to delete it which is showing in every incident or CQ.

[image]

Comment: Here you go: +5, means you can post the screenshot.

Comment: @VonC. Thanks for the Reputation...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in ClearQuest...

Answer (score 1):

First off your question's tagged wrong - I'd suggest correctly tagging it as "clearquest" so the right people see it.

ClearQuest is also highly modifiable so it's really hard to answer without knowing more about how your schema's designed, exactly what you're doing, etc.

Talk to your admin team if you can - they should be able to tell you exactly how it's all been designed. Otherwise you'll need to explain a lot more about how your schema works.

Comment: Might be there is need to mention the scheme but I have one record Type i.e. Branch name so that UCM activity can be attached while check in correct branch and I mistakenly put the wrong branch name . So is there any way to edit the same.

Comment: Okay .. a branch name doesn't have it's own record type, so I'm guessing you're using something like BaseUCMActivity, which is a stateful record (i.e. it can progress through multiple states). You may be able to modify the field in a later state, depending on how the record's designed.

Alternatively if you've admin rights, you could modify the field so it can be changed in certain states (like on SUBMT), or via the MODIFY action. If you don't have admin rights, you'll need to speak to whoever does.

Comment: Sure Garry, my ClearQuest design is such that to achieve UCM I need to select branch name while creating Incident and assign to Developer so that Developer would not check-in the code in other branch. And while selecting the branch name, I have done the mistake in name which I want to edit.

Answer (score 1):

To modify first drag the query to your personal queries folder before modifying  use the query editer to make your change and  then use display editer tabs to setup how the query result and displayed.

Comment: But I am referring here the record value which you get when click on new as I mentioned in question pic.

Comment: A change request record usually starts out in the Submitted state..The first thing to do is to assign the change request to the engineer responsible for that section of code.The exact process of working with records, including the states the record can
be in and the actions available in each state, depends on the ClearQuest
schema you are using and any customizations you have made to it.

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding one more snapshot, through which I have put the wrong value and now finding the solution or button from where I can delete the value.